# In AngularJS How can I get a total from filtered results?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular with PHP to retrieve a filtered list of invoices. I want to show the total of all of the filtered results.

This is my Controller file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.min_date = 000000;
    $scope.max_date = 999999;

    $http.get('getinvoice.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.invoices = data;
    });

    $scope.dateFilter = (function(invoice) {
        return (invoice.dateshort > $scope.min_date - 1 && invoice.dateshort < $scope.max_date + 1);
    });

    $scope.totalPrice = function() {
        var total = 0;
        for (count = 0; count < $scope.invoices.length; count++) {
            total += $scope.invoices[count].total;
        }
        return total;
    }
}]);
```

And Here is the HTML page:

```
<section id="searchpage" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MyController' >
  <div class="search" >

    <label>Search: </label>
    <input id ='search' ng-model="query" placeholder="Search Invoices" autofocus>
    <label>Min Date:</label><input id='mindate' ng-model="min_date" />
    <label>Max Date:</label><input id='maxdate' ng-model="max_date" />

    <br><br>   
  </div>

  <table class="customerlist" ng-show="query" ng-init="tot=0.00">
    <tr>
      <th class='border'>Type</th>
      <th class='border'>Date</th>
      <th class='border'>Customer Name</th>
      <th class='border'>Vehichle</th>
      <th class='border'>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr  class="customerrow" ng-repeat="invoice in filtered = (invoices | filter: query | filter: dateFilter)">
      <td class='border'>{{invoice.type}}</td>
      <td class='border'>{{invoice.dateshort}}</td>
      <td class='border'>{{invoice.name}}</td>
      <td class='border'>{{invoice.vehicle}}</td>
      <td calss='total'>{{invoice.total |currency }}</td>
      <td class='border'><a class="button" href="invre.php?id={{invoice.id}}&type={{invoice.type}}">View Invoice</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
  <p>{{filtered.length}} Results</p>
  <p id = 'tline'>Total: {{totalPrice()}}</p>
</section>
```

Currently this produces the totals from everything. However, there are two problems with this.  First, it returns a list of all of the totals:

```
Total: 0108.77614.860.0056.990.000.000.0032.4286.4930.9530.95
```

Second this includes all of the results, not the filtered results.  How can I fix this?

Comment: on a side note: I suggest not to use `<br>`s to space things, but instead create ad hoc classes and style them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `$scope.filtered` in controller. In `total()`, `$scope.invoices` should change to `$scope.filtered`

```
$scope.totalPrice = function() {
        var total = 0;
        for (count = 0; count < $scope.filtered.length; count++) {
            total += $scope.filtered[count].total;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you very much.  To fix the other problem I went into the PHP and made sure that it was sending through float values.

Answer (score 0):

From your posted result, it seems that the total is a concatenation (not an addition), as if each `invoice.total` was a string, instead of a number.

So for your first issue, I suggest you double check what it gets returned from `$http.get`. Maybe a conversion in client code is needed, or (better yet) a correct conversion from PHP entity to JSON is needed server-side.

For your second issue, @Aasem Gautam is right: you should total only on filtered invoices, not on all of them. Also, instead of looping on the array, you could go a little more *functional*, so to say:

```
$scope.totalPrice = function() {
  var initialValue = 0;

  var total = $scope.filtered.reduce(function (partial, invoice) {
    return partial + invoice.total;
  }, initialValue);

  return total;
};
```

See [MDN Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for ref.

**Disclaimer**: edited here by hand, there could be some syntax error. Please ask about it in case.

Comment: Changing the total value to a float did fix that problem thank you very much.

Comment: that's great. I suggest to also try the switch from array loops to a more functional approach, wherever you can. Code gets usually more expressive.